# I need Parent Id sum the child's amounts and the child sum its childs and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with two columns accountCode,allocationBudget

!(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kaGlpar7tyKmqUSqrLEgVIdz4LLzQt3c)

What I want to do is every parent in the field of his allocations, the total allocations of it's child and for the child will also be in the field of it's allocations the total allocations of its children and so the last child get its allocation only

```
select accountCode,sum(allocationBudget)
from T1
group by accountCode
having SUBSTRING(accountCode,1,len(accountCode))=accountCode
```

Required result like this :
!(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mUDLWFQU9bYsuD4IhMyxExxeyaDOzWSL)

I hope this is understandable and I have been able to get the idea to you.
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self-join.

```
select
    T1.accountCode,
    SUM(T2.allocationBudget) as allocationBudget
from T1
left join T1 as T2 on SUBSTRING(T2.accountCode,1,LEN(T1.accountCode)) = T1.accountCode
group by T1.accountCode
```

Answer (score 1):

If I assume first 7 digit from your AcountCode is the parent ID, this following script should give your expected result.

```
SELECT A.AcountCode,
CASE 
    WHEN B.AcountCode IS NOT NULL THEN B.Total 
    ELSE A.AllocationBudget 
END AllocationBudget
FROM your_table A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
    LEFT(CAST(AcountCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)),7) AcountCode,
    SUM(AllocationBudget) Total 
    FROM your_table 
    GROUP BY LEFT(CAST(AcountCode AS VARCHAR(MAX)),7)
)B ON A.AcountCode = B.AcountCode
```